# Web form filling using digital writing pads

Tags: asp.net

I own a website, in which my users will fill a particular form many times in a single day.

All I need is I want to give them a digital writing pad, so that they write the content in the pad instead of typing. And I need the written content to get automatically stored in my website form.

Will this be possible, if yes how???

Pleas help me on this.

Regards
Vinoth

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "digital writing pad"? Do you want to store Handwriting, wysiwyg text or plain text?
What do you have so far?

Comment: I want to store handwritten text, to get stored in a online form, it can get saved either as plain text or as an image

Comment: You probably need to use custom tool, ether by javascript, ether by flash, ether by java... I am wondering if all ready exist.

Comment: Which writing pad will be the best for customization, any suggestions???